# ERROR No subscriber package version found for package id 'XXX' while creating package in CI/CD

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, unlocked-package, gitlab

we have an unlocked package which we deploy via GitLab CI/CD. The deployment went well until we added the required `--codecoverage` to the gitlab-ci.yml, which we got from the [official salesforce gitlab](https://gitlab.com/sfdx/sfdx-cicd-template/-/blob/master/Salesforce.gitlab-ci.yml).

Unlike [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/320824/error-no-subscriber-package-version-found-for-package-id-0hoid) we don't have problems with code deployment, and the code coverage is around 80%.

The pipeline has multiple steps:

- Create a scratch org and deploy metadata
- Run tests
- Create a package version          <- This one fails
- Deploy package on dev sandbox
- Deploy package on staging sandbox (manual)
- Deploy package on production      (manual)

The used command is the following:

`sfdx force:package:version:create --targetdevhubusername DEVHUB --package <Package ID> --versionnumber 1.25.0.NEXT --installationkeybypass --wait 10 --codecoverage --json`

We also checked `sfdx force:package:list --targetdevhubusername <DevHubAlias>` and the package is there.

**sfdx-project.json:**

```json
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "package": "<packageName>",
            "versionName": "White Tulip",
            "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
            "default": true
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sourceApiVersion": "47.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "<packageName>": "<packageId>"
    }
}
```

The last version deployed was 1.24.0.1. Does anyone have an idea what went wrong?

EDIT:

We tried to get more information by running `sfdx force:package:version:create:report -i <requestId> --targetdevhubusername <username>`. This lead us to the following error:

```
=== Errors
(1) Apex Test Failure: Class.<class>.<method>: line 137, column 1
Class.<class>.<method>: line 58, column 1
Class.<class>.<method>: line 100, column 1 System.UnexpectedException: Apex approval lock/unlock api preference not enabled.
```

(changed class and method names)
which is a bit strange, because when we checked all used orgs, the setting was enabled on all of them.

Comment: Can you check if you are connected to right DevHub org from gitlab CI?

Comment: We are using the authurl we got when issuing ' sfdx force:org:display -u <DevHubAlias> --verbose' as a CI variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed on the [developer forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000IZgk), the problem was solved by giving the below force:package:version:create command

```
sfdx force:package:version:create --targetdevhubusername DEVHUB --package <Package ID> --versionnumber 1.25.0.NEXT --installationkeybypass --wait 10 --codecoverage --json -f config/project-scratch-def.json
```

And by ensuring that Apex Setting ApexApprovalLockUnlock
is added under OrgPreferenceSetttings in the definition file

I will pass on the feedback around including this in the documentation

Comment: How do you add the Apex Setting ApexApprovalLockUnlock under OrgPreferenceSetttings in the definition file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by a Salesforce engineer. The solution was the following:

> This error is due to the Apex Setting "ApexApprovalLockUnlock" so while creating package version it is advised to define scratch org definition file like this -
> `sfdx force:package:version:create --targetdevhubusername DEVHUB --package <Package ID> --versionnumber 1.25.0.NEXT --installationkeybypass --wait 10 --codecoverage --json -f config/project-scratch-def.json`
> and make sure this Apex Setting under OrgPreferenceSetttings added in the definition file - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_orgpreferencesettings.htm?search_text=ApexApprovalLockUnlock

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the generic error didn't tell me much "no subscriber package version found..." but when I tried to list the packages using:

```
sfdx force:package:list
```

I got the actual error which was:

```
Error (1): Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: ip restricted
```